# Why console for isGuest is not printed. I'm getting output as The Id is 1

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

```
function getGuestUserID(v)
{console.log('The Id is',v)};

function isGuest(val){ console.log('hl') 
return false};

function err(e) { console.log("error", e); }

Promise.resolve(1).then(isGuest && getGuestUserID).catch(err);
```

Comment: Because it never gets called. Only one function, the result of the expression, is passed as a callback.

Answer (score 1):

You never call the `isGuest` function, and it's not used as an argument that is passed to the `.then()` method. The arguments of a funnction are evaluated first before the `.then()` method is called, so your code is the analogous to:

```js
const thenFn = isGuest && getGuestUserID;
Promise.resolve(1).then(thenFn).catch(err);
```

Because `isGuest` is a function object, it is cosidered truthy, so `thenFn` gets assigned to the `getGuestUserID` function. Notice here how you're not calling the `isGuest()` method in this case.

You can instead create a callback function that handles this for your when your Promise resolves:

```js
Promise.resolve(1).then((v) => isGuest(v) && getGuestUserID(v)).catch(err);
```

or you can use an if-statement to mak it a bit more readable:

```js
Promise.resolve(1).then((v) => {
  if(isGuest(v))
     return getGuestUserID(v);
}).catch(err);
```

The above two examples are slightly different in what they return. So depending on your use case you may want to keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Code to create a promise chain is executed synchronously. The following *statement*

```
 Promise.resolve(1).then(isGuest && getGuestUserID).catch(err);
```

is executed as follows:

1. The JavaScript engine calls `Promise.resolve(1)`, which returns a promise fulfilled with the number `1`,
2. The argument expression `isGuest && getGuestUserID` is evaluated, which in JavaScript results in the value `getGuestUserID`, a function object.
3. The `then` method of the promise created in step 1 is called with `getGuestUserID` as argument.
4. Because the promise is already fulfilled, `then` method code puts a job in the Promise Job Queue to call `then`'s first argument (`getGuestUserID`) with the fulfilled value of the promise, `1`, as argument.
5. The `catch` method of the promise returned from the `then` call in step 3 is called with argument `err`, a function. This call returns a promise which is not used.
6. Execution continues after the Promise chain statement,  possibly executing synchronous code that follows it, before returning control to task management components of the event loop.
7. Any jobs in the Promise Job Queue are executed on a FIFO basis, which includes the job put there in step 4.
8. Promise job execution calls `getGuestUserID` with argument `1`, which prints "The id is 1" on the console.

---

If you call `then` on a pending promise, the part about putting a job in the Promise Job Queue described in step 4 doesn't happen when `then` is called and is delayed until when (and if) the promise is actually  fulfilled or rejected (and hence no longer pending).